# react-router Link typescript error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6, react-router

I just started to add TypeScript on my React project, and I can't figure out of this error :

```
import {Link} from 'react-router';
Module '"/Users/.../node_modules/@types/react-router/index"' has no exported member 'Link'.
```

The `Link` component exists in `react-router` (the code is working), but TypeScript does not recognise it. I've added the `@types/react-router`, and it seems not to implements the `Link`. Any ideas ?

Extract from my `package.json` :

```
"@types/react": "^15.0.25",
"@types/react-dom": "^15.5.0",
"@types/react-router": "^4.0.11",
"@types/reactstrap": "^4.3.4",

...

"react": "^15.4.2",
"react-dom": "^15.4.2",
"react-router": "^3.0.2",
"reactstrap": "^4.2.0"

...

"typescript": "^2.3.3",
```

Comment: what version of react-router?

Comment: Post updated with versions used

Comment: your @types/react-router needs to be V3 to match react-router

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have `react-router` version 3, but the @types package for version 4.  Version 4 of react-router moved a lot of the library into the `react-router-dom` package, which is why their types are not in the `@types/react-router` v4 packages.

You should remove the incorrect type package with:

```
npm un @types/react-router
```

Then install the correct types with:

```
npm i --save-dev @types/react-router@3
```

Comment: Instead of downgrading the @types/react-router version, I prefered upgrading my router version to v4. Then the `import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'` worked as well. Thx for your help :)