# How to send params using react-router-dom without a <Link> tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-navigation, react-router-dom, react-bootstrap

I am using react-router-dom v^6.0.0-beta.1 with React v^17.0.1 and I am navigating from 1 page to another by clicking on a card out of a list of cards:

### PlayersPage.tsx

```
/** @jsxImportSource @emotion/react */
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Page } from './Page';
import { PageTitle } from './PageTitle';
import { Button, Card } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { css } from '@emotion/react';
import pic from '../assets/samurai.png';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

function PlayersPage() {
  interface PlayersDataType {
    id: number;
    handle: string;
    role: string;
    avatar: string;
    specialAbilities: {
      playerId: number;
      authority: number;
      charismaticLeadership: number;
      combatSense: number;
      credibility: number;
      family: number;
      interface: number;
      juryRig: number;
      medicalTech: number;
      resources: number;
      streedeal: number;
    };
    stats: {
      playerId: number;
      int: number;
      ref: number;
      tech: number;
      cool: number;
      attr: number;
      luck: number;
      ma: number;
      body: number;
      emp: number;
      run: number;
      leap: number;
      lift: number;
    };
  }

  //const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [playersData, setPlayersData] = useState<Array<PlayersDataType>>([]);
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const createNew = () => {
    navigate('../Create');
  };

  const handleSelect = () => {
    navigate('../Player');
  };

  //Fetch all players from database
  useEffect(() => {
    //setIsLoading(true);
    fetch('https://localhost:44326/api/Players/all')
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.ok) {
          return response.json();
        }
      })
      .then((data) => setPlayersData(data));
    //.then(setIsLoading(false));
  }, []);

  return (
    <Page>
      <div>
        <PageTitle>Toons</PageTitle>
        <div
          css={css`
            justify-content: center;
            margin-left: 255px;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
          `}
        >
          <button onClick={createNew}>Create New</button>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div //Every card is listed in 1 column
        css={css`
          flex-direction: column;
          margin-left: 40px;
        `}
      >
        {playersData.map((data) => (
          <div key={data.id}>
            <Card
              css={css`
                display: flex;
                width: 500px;
                height: 200px;
                flex-direction: column;
                //border: 2px solid black;
                box-shadow: 0 3px 7px 0 rgba(30, 38, 46, 0.21);
                cursor: pointer;
                :hover {
                  transform: scale(
                    1.2
                  ); /* (150% zoom - Note: if the zoom is too large, it will go outside of the viewport) */
                }
              `}
              onClick={handleSelect}
            >
              <div
                css={css`
                  display: flex;
                  flex-direction: row;
                  //border: 2px solid orange;
                `}
              >
                <Card.Img
                  src={pic}
                  alt="No photo found."
                  css={css`
                    margin: 5px 10px 10px 10px;
                    width: 150px;
                    height: 150px;
                    border-radius: 50%;
                    box-shadow: 0 3px 7px 0 rgba(30, 38, 46, 0.21);
                    //border: 2px solid black;
                  `}
                />
                <Card.Body
                  css={css`
                    flex: 1;
                    flex-direction: row;
                    //border: 2px solid purple;
                  `}
                >
                  <div
                    css={css`
                      display: flex;
                      flex-direction: row;
                      //justify-content: space-between;
                      flex-wrap: wrap;
                    `}
                  >
                    <Card.Text>Int:</Card.Text>
                    <Card.Text>{data.stats.int}</Card.Text>
                    <Card.Text>Ref:</Card.Text>
                    <Card.Text>{data.stats.ref}</Card.Text>
                    <Card.Text>Tech:</Card.Text>
                    <Card.Text>{data.stats.tech}</Card.Text>
                    <Card.Text>Cool:</Card.Text>
                    <Card.Text>{data.stats.cool}</Card.Text>
                    <Card.Text>Attr:</Card.Text>
                    <Card.Text>{data.stats.attr}</Card.Text>
                    <Card.Text>Luck:</Card.Text>
                    <Card.Text>{data.stats.luck}</Card.Text>
                    <Card.Text>Ma:</Card.Text>
                    <Card.Text>{data.stats.ma}</Card.Text>
                    <Card.Text>Body:</Card.Text>
                    <Card.Text>{data.stats.body}</Card.Text>
                    <Card.Text>Emp:</Card.Text>
                    <Card.Text>{data.stats.emp}</Card.Text>
                    <Card.Text>Run:</Card.Text>
                    <Card.Text>{data.stats.run}</Card.Text>
                    <Card.Text>Leap:</Card.Text>
                    <Card.Text>{data.stats.leap}</Card.Text>
                    <Card.Text>Lift:</Card.Text>
                    <Card.Text>{data.stats.lift}</Card.Text>
                  </div>
                </Card.Body>
              </div>
              <Card.Title
                css={css`
                  display: flex;
                  width: 150px;
                  flex-direction: row;
                  justify-content: center;
                  font-weight: bold;
                  margin-bottom: 10px;
                `}
              >
                {data.handle}, {data.role}
              </Card.Title>
            </Card>
            <br></br>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </Page>
  );
}

export default PlayersPage;
```

I would like to send the `data.id` of whichever card that the user clicks on.

Is there any way I can send `data.id` as a param here with the onClick function:

```
  <div key={data.id}>
            <Card
              css={css`
                display: flex;
                width: 500px;
                height: 200px;
                flex-direction: column;
                //border: 2px solid black;
                box-shadow: 0 3px 7px 0 rgba(30, 38, 46, 0.21);
                cursor: pointer;
                :hover {
                  transform: scale(
                    1.2
                  ); /* (150% zoom - Note: if the zoom is too large, it will go outside of the viewport) */
                }
              `}
              onClick={handleSelect}
            >
```

and somehow send it here:

```
 const handleSelect = () => {
    navigate('../Player');
  };
```

and then use that id on another page?

EDIT:

This is what I am trying now:

```
onClick={() => handleSelect(data.id)}
```

which I believe is correct. Then in the handleSelect function:

```
 const handleSelect = (id: number) => {
    history.push(pathname: '/Player',
      state: {  
        id: id, 
      },)
  }
```

However I am getting 3 errors on this: `Property 'push' does not exist on type 'History'.ts(2339)` and `Cannot find name 'pathname'.ts(2304)` and same error for `state`.

EDIT 2:

I have added   `const history = useHistory();` and updated the handleSelect function as follows:

```
 const handleSelect = (id: number) => {
    history.push({
      pathname: '/Player',
      state: {
        id: id,
      },
    });
  };
```

Everything seems fine except the typescript error `Module '"react-router-dom"' has no exported member 'useHistory'.ts(2305)`.

Comment: You can use useHistory hook.
check this : [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59464337/how-to-send-params-in-usehistory-of-react-router-dom)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this:

```
onClick={()=>handleSelect(data.id)}
```

and modify your `handleSelect` as follow:

```
const handleSelect = (id) => {
    this.props.router.push({
      pathname: '/pathname',
      state: {
        id: id
      }
    })
  };
```

or use `useHistory`:

```
const handleSelect = (id) => {
    history.push(pathname: '/YOUR PATH',
      state: {  
        id: id, 
      },)
  }
```

---

for your edit section:

1. import useHistory and use it:

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

// in your component define a history variable
const history = useHistory();

// then use it whenever you want:
history.push({
  pathname: '/your path', //change the value to whatever you want
  state: {  
    id: id, // you can add other variables as well
  },
});
```

2. now you can access this variable in your destination component:
   in class component:

```
this.props.location
```

in functional component:

```
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

const location = useLocation();
let id  = location.state.id;
```

Comment: On the first method I get an error on id: ````Parameter 'id' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7006)```` and on this: ````'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation.ts(2683)
PlayersPage.tsx(11, 10): An outer value of 'this' is shadowed by this container.````

Comment: the first method is for class components! if you use a functional component you should use `useHistory`, have you defined useHistory? you should use it as follow: `const history = useHistory();`

Comment: Ok with the history method I get these error: ````Property 'push' does not exist on type 'History'.ts(2339)```` , ````Cannot find name 'pathname'.ts(2304)````, and ````Cannot find name 'state'.ts(2304)````.

Comment: I edited my question to show where I'm at.

Comment: I get the error: ````Module '"react-router-dom"' has no exported member 'useHistory'.ts(2305)```` I have run yarn install and yarn add @types/react-router-dom but the issue persists

Comment: I updated my question again, but that typescript error is the only issue now.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44420631/react-router-link-typescript-error and https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/14062

Comment: Ok the second one did fix the issue, but now I get the exact same error on useNavigate instead...

Comment: That actually caused a lot of my other imports to develop the same issue. I'm going to have to just open another question to try to fix typescript issues. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Hey so react-router-dom version 6 does not have useHistory, how can I do this without it?

Comment: I did not know that, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63471931/using-history-with-react-router-dom-v6

Comment: yes that's how I was navigating to begin with. But I need to pass params with it. I think I know how to do this but I'm getting too many typescript errors to test. I have opened a question for this if you know anything about typescript: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68907952/react-router-dom-version-6-usenavigate-argument-of-type-whatever-number

Answer (score 2):

In your `handleSelect` method you need to pass the `data.id` param.

```
onClick={handleSelect(data.id)}
```

And take care of it in your handler. But you have to wrap the function like this.

```
const handleSelect = (clickEvent) => (dataId) {
    //dataId will be available to use here
    navigate('../Player/');
};
```

Then I would have a look at the `useHistory` hook as the history prop is considered to be legacy.

```
import React from 'react';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

const Hello = () => {
  const history = useHistory();
  const handleClick = () => history.push('/goodbye');

  return (
    <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>
      Goodbye
    </button>
  );
};

export default Hello;
```

So when you push to the history URL you can create a route that uses that parameter. Something like this:

```
history.push('/yourURL/:dataId');
```

Then on that page, you can pull that parameter down and your app there can consume it.

Comment: using `onClick={handleSelect(data.id)}` is not correct, you should change it to `onClick={()=>handleSelect(data.id)}`